# XCode IOS simulator doesn't put my task to background

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

I have XCode 8.3.3., and testing an app that makes REST API calls. When open another app in foreground ( some of the stock simulator apps: calendar, news, etc. ), my app still continues to make periodic REST calls. This is not what happens on the real device (iPhone 5S). It makes the calls, even if I Lock my simulator out.

Is this intended behavior? How can I get real device compliance?
Thanks.

Comment: same issue here. Good questions.

Comment: When running under Xcode your app will never be suspended.  Things like `Timer`s continue to fire and your app will not be terminated for exceeding its background time limit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good news: As of Xcode 9 Beta 3 we suspend background processes in the Simulator.

Comment: Why is this good news? I'd like to test background processing tasks on a Simulator.

Comment: Suspension mostly follows normal system policy so if you have a background task your app won't get suspended. One exception is audio playback: if you are registered for background audio we don't suspend in the sim even if you aren't playing.

Answer (score 0):

The question is answered in the comments.

Basically XCode simulator doesn't enforce background tasks.